# Convert MySQL datetime to different timezones

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, timezone

I've been reading around here and Google about the way MySQL stores datetime and date, and I can't seem to get a good understanding of it, and what I need to do to accomplish my goals. I'm also not entirely sure my host is set up correctly as it doesn't seem to behave as I expect it to.

My goal is: Datetime and Date would be stored as UTC +00:00. Then, when the database is queried with PHP, the datetime and date would be converted based on the user's settings before being displayed.

Querying the server with SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone; returns SYSTEM for both.

Also, if I try doing a query with SET time_zone '-05:00'; it does not change the datetime that is output from the server. Changing it to any other value also does not change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL only ever interacts with the server it's running on so it will only ever give the time zone of that server. You'd have to [get the time zone on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone).

Edit:

MySQL doesn't have a time zone literal so you can use [UTC_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Futc-timestamp) to get the current time in UTC or you can convert the time elsewhere.

Comment: Right, so how would I force it to save the datetime as UTC 00:00, then convert it on pull?

Comment: Convert it to UTC before storing it. If all you need is a timestamp then use [UTC_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Futc-timestamp).

Comment: If I understand this correctly UTC_TIMESTAP() (instead of say, NOW()) will store the current UTC 00:00 time? Then how would I manipulate it afterwards? Is there a function in MySQL/PHP that can do it for me?